# scheduling task is no more able to access the remote computer administrative drives on the execution of the script

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, scheduled-tasks, superuser

I have scheduled a task which runs a VBScript to copy the remote computer files (`\\remotecomputerIP\c$`) through administrative drives to the host machine (local) over the LAN network. It was working pretty well (in accessing the administrative drives) before changing the remote computer login password. However, after changing the remote computer login password, through scheduling it is no more able to access the remote computer administrative drives.

Note that I am able to run the script manually which will work as in accessing the remote administrative drives.

Have restarted my local computer, no luck.

P.S: platform is Windows 7.
The task is running as Administrator.
Run with highest privileges checkbox is ticked.

Comment: The user running the scheduled task must have the same username and password as the corresponding account on the remote host (in a workgroup environment). Ideally (in a domain environment) you'd use a dedicated domain account for something like this, but even then you'd need to update the password stored with the task whenever you change the password of the account.

Comment: BTW, please post questions like this on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) since this isn't programming-related.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ansgar Wiechers .we are using workgroup. you are right. to access other computer resources in the work group, both should have same username and password. now changing the password for remote computer created a chaos. I am still wondering why only for task scheduling ( though i am not able to convince much from the available online resources) where i am able to access the resources of remote computer on the work group by running the script manually after mapping drive.

Comment: I have reverted the remote and local computer to use the same password. the scheduling task still unable to connect through the script. and also what I found is running the script through scheduling task considering the date format d/M/yyyy format , where in the manually running of the script considering dd/MM/yyyy format according to date format settings of the local computer.